# My req to add all input fields (created by picklist) value on total field by on blur event

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

Here in my code i am getting first field value only.

```
<apex:page standardController="Entertainment__c" extensions="ScreenDetailController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" docType="xhtml-1.0-strict">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function TotalVal(){
            var x ;
        //alert(document.getElementById("Audi").value);
            for(var i=0;i< $('select[id$=ScreenValueID]').val() ; i++){
                x = document.getElementById("Audi").value;
            }
            document.getElementById("total").value = document.getElementById("Audi").value;
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <b>Screen :</b><apex:selectlist value="{!picklistselectedvalue}" id="ScreenValueID" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!SortTheList}"/>
        </apex:selectlist>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!data}" var="e">
                    <apex:column >
                        <B>Audi {!e.count}</B>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                        <input value="{!e.name}" id="Audi" onblur="TotalVal()"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageblockTable>    
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <b>Total :</b><output id="total"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, welcome to SFSE. With the information you have provided, its not very clear as what are you trying to achieve and what is your issue. Please take a moment on [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and also recommend you to [**edit**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/229759/edit) your post so that you can provide much more details, relevant code snippet, your issue and your effort to resolve this. Providing these details will help your question get more attention and thus resolution.